# pthread and select

Tags: c

there.

I am trying to program a server.

The server receive some information from client

and it sends the information to the other server and it receive the response.

Do I need to use select() on this case?

or Pthread only is enough to do this.

my server has many clients connecting concurrently

please answer me kindly.

And if there is, please tell me the source code or site that I can refer to

Comment: It depends on how many connection you anticipate to handle concurrently. If it's only a few (like around five, no more than ten) then using blocking sockets and threads is ok. More than that and it might be a good idea to look into `select` and similar methods.

Comment: Building on Joachim Pileborg's comment, the two main POSIX methods to handle multiple socket connections in one thread are `select` and `poll`.  Linux also offers `epoll`; Some BSDs have `kqueue`; and Windows has I/O Completions Ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to implementing a server that handles multiple clients is to create a pthread for each client connection, so that you can read/write each connection in a dedicated thread. It sounds like what you're asking is "if I have a pthread for each client connection, do I still need to use `select`?"

In a very simple server you might be able to dispense with `select`: the connection thread looks something like:

```
do {
      read(conn, cmd);
      response = process(cmd);
      write(conn, response);
} while (cmd != DONE)
```

But, even with a dedicated client thread, you may find that you still want to use `select` to check for available input before calling `read` on the client connection. For example, if you need to be able to implement an idle timeout on your connection, you won't want to just do a blocking `read`.

Comment: The general thrust of this answer is sound, but the extremely high level pseudo-code would be better not looking like C lest it be thought more complete than it is.  Specifically, if doesn't check for errors from `read` or `write`, nor for either successfully transferring to/from only part of the indicated buffer, nor for EOF....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by using pthread to communicate between client and server - my experience of pthread is the POSIX Thread library which doesn't relate to communications....

Documentation and examples of how to use select are broadly available:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/sasc/doc750/html/lr2/select.htm
http://www.lowtek.com/sockets/select.html

are examples of what you might find by searching "select c" using google....

Comment: He's presumably referring to the model where every time the server `accept`s a new connection, it spawns a new thread to handle the connection.

Comment: @Hurkyl: equally, you can spawn many threads that block in `accept()` on the listening socket....

Comment: yes I mean that every time the server accepts a new connection, I should create a thread. in this case, I wonder I should use select() in server or I can just exclude it